# Rails: How to read a list of images from a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a URL like below->

```
images = open("example.com").read
```

which returns

```
<center>
<font size=-1>
<img src=example.com/show?1><br>1 image<p>
<img src=example.com/show?2><br>2 image<p>
<img src=example.com/show?3><br>3 image<p>
</font>
```

I want to capture each of these on backend and send them to the front end. 
So far I was sending the resulting html directly to front end where it was displayed. But now I want to capture it on backend and then send each one to UI. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) for this. You can then do something like

```
html_string = open("example.com").read
nokogiri_html_string = Nokogiri::HTML( html_string )
image_tags = nokogiri_html_string.css('img')
image_sources = nokogiri_html_string.css('img').map{ |i| i['src'] }
```

Hope this will help.